# Indefinido o imperfecto: acción que sucede en mitad de otra en el pasado

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto

Estoy tratando de traducir esta frase de inglés:

> When I was in school, the easiest points were the ones I had to learn by heart.

¿Puedo usar el imperfecto para todos los verbos?

> Cuando estaba en la escuela, los puntos más fáciles eran los que tenía que aprender de memoria.

Estoy confundido, por qué no podría decir:

> Cuando estaba en la escuela, los puntos más fáciles fueron los que tuve que aprender de memoria.

La segunda parte de la frase parece "una acción que sucede en mitad de otra en el pasado". ¿Me equivoco?

Comment: Para mi ambas traducciones son correctas y significan lo mismo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El uso de los dos (o tres) verbos en pretérito imperfecto hace que las acciones parezcan simultáneas o paralelas, y ambas dotadas del aspecto durativo del imperfecto:

- Cuando **sucedía** A, **sucedía** B. (B comenzó y terminó junto con A, o en un momento indeterminado durante A.)

En cambio, la irrupción del indefinido (también conocido como pretérito perfecto simple) en un contexto temporal con imperfecto hace que la acción en pretérito perfecto suene como completada en algún momento más preciso durante el lapso descripto por el imperfecto.

Sin mayor contexto, la traducción habitual de la oración en cuestión sería, a mi juicio, la primera.

La segunda sería más probable si en el contexto ya se usó ese tiempo, y en ese caso uno sentiría la tentación de usar el perfecto simple para ambos verbos:

> - ¿Cuándo fue que tuviste que aprender de memoria?
> - **Tuve** que aprender de memoria cuando **estaba/estuve** en la escuela.

Answer (score 0):

Los dos son correctos, pero de acuerdo a los usos del pretérito imperfecto y el pretérito simple, el significado cambia.

Cuando estaba en la escuela, los puntos más fáciles **eran los que tenía** que aprender de memoria (*descripción/repetitiva, y no sabemos si los aprendió.*)

Cuando estaba en la escuela siempre los puntos **eran los que tenía** que (*sólo sabemos lo que siempre le pasaba sin indicar duración o la culminación, no sabemos si esos conceptos los aprendió*)

Cuando estaba en la escuela, los puntos más fáciles **fueron los que tuve** que aprender de memoria
(*específicamente indica lo que aprendió en ese período, la acción que completó en ese tiempo en la escuela.*)

El significado es lo que le hizo (completó) durante ese período escolar.